# vb.net datagridview dataerror commit

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

Hello friends and happy new year!
I am confused about an error in my vb.net application.
I have a datagridview which is databound on a bindingsource.
I have datadrigview SelectionMode to FullRowSelect.
When the form is loaded I have:

```
Me.BuildingsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PolwarehouseDataSet.buildings) ' buildings
Me.PeriodsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PolwarehouseDataSet.periods) ' periods
Me.PhasesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PolwarehouseDataSet.phases) ' phases
BuildingsDataGridView.ClearSelection()
```

I can see all the data (2 rows). The problem appears when I press the second row.
I have the below message:
[Error when I press the second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cOVZ.png)

After I pressed OK I can move to any of the rows. **Sometimes I lose the cell values** on the Period Field on datagridview, no the database.
I understand that when I select other rows, something goes wrong and delete the value in my not null field and I have the error. But I cannot understand why it removed from the datagrid.
I follow this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror(v=vs.110).aspx from Microsoft and I get the error: Error happened commit, commit error.

The same issue happened when I sort datagridview, via pressing any column name.

Here is the datagrid: [My datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbtlu.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the error says `column buildperiod doesn't support null`...i hope you know what it means ??

Comment: however, you can easily ignore the error by using a `Try` statement

Comment: I know what does mean. But as I wrote when I load to datagrid I have data inside. The problem appears when I select the second row. Then the error appears and sometimes I lose the cell not null value. The try catch does not solve the problem because when I lose the cell value and for instance add a new row, fistrly lose the value and secondly I cannot save

Comment: do you have any custom events on the grid that you aren't showing us?  I assume the grid is editable

Comment: @Ctznkane525, thanks for the response. I have not any event in datagridview. I have period and phase columns that are not null. When form loaded, datagridview gets datasource from bindingsource. Those fields are filled. The issue is when I select the second row. Datagrid tries to remove the value of period field, and gives me the error message.

Comment: Can we see that code

Comment: I think that I understand where is the error, but I cannot solve it. In the same form I have the datagridview and below the same datasource to details mode. The 2 fields in the details mode are combobox and used as lookup. I setup the datasource, displaymember, valuemember and selectedvalue. When form loaded i set all the comboboxed to be selectedindex=-1 (no selection). This is why i get the error. But if i do not set the selectedindex, then lose the values in datagrid (in database remains until i press save)

Comment: I found the solution! I redesign my lookup tables and fill the right fields! Thanks!